# How to get current Field Name in a custom field type

Tags: inheritance, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm attempting to retrieve the current field name on a custom Sitecore field I'm building. In other words, if my custom field type is applied to a field named "Meta title", I need to be able to retrieve that name.

[This tutorial](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Creating%20a%20Composite%20Custom%20Field/Define%20the%20Properties%20of%20the%20Control.aspx) implies that all you have to do is create a public auto-property called FieldName and the rest is history... sadly, it doesn't appear to work (FieldName is always null or empty).

Any ideas? I've tried inheriting from `Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Control` and `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Text` with no luck.

Comment: What are you attempting to do with your custom field that requires you to know the field name?

Comment: My field checks for possible duplicate item titles by searching the Sitecore system index for similarly named items. I need to know the field name in order to build the Lucene query.

Comment: This is also useful when you have jquery operations (in my case hide and unhide) in your control and multiple fields in one item - when you don't take the name into account hide and unhide affects all fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have access to the Field ID in your control by creating a FieldID property. This should equate to the ID of the Template Field item that defines the field. Thus you can get the name of the field by

```
var fieldItem = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(this.FieldID);
var fieldName = fieldItem.Name;
```

The full list of properties that Sitecore may set on your control can be found in `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter.SetProperties`.

```
ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(editor, "ID", field.ControlID);
ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(editor, "ItemID", field.ItemField.Item.ID.ToString());
ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(editor, "ItemVersion", field.ItemField.Item.Version.ToString());
ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(editor, "ItemLanguage", field.ItemField.Item.Language.ToString());
ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(editor, "FieldID", field.ItemField.ID.ToString());
ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(editor, "Source", field.ItemField.Source);
ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(editor, "ReadOnly", readOnly);
ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(editor, "Disabled", readOnly);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it appears ID refers to the Web Control's ID (ex: FIELD23212622), not the ID of the Template Field Item. Humm...

Comment: Sorry about that, tracked down the solution and fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. I just realized who you are! haha. Nice presentation on Page Editor yesterday!